# Mapbox proportional symbol feature radius

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm new to Mapbox GL JS and struggling with data-driven styling.  I'd like to scale my circle features proportionally based on a value in my data source (a Google Sheet).  Here's a code snippet:

```
  map.addLayer({
    id: 'csvData',
    type: 'circle',
    source: {
     type: 'geojson',
     data: data
    },
    paint: {
      'circle-color': '#dd502c',
      'circle-stroke-width': 1,
      'circle-stroke-color': '#dd502c',
      'circle-opacity': 0.5,
      "circle-radius": {
        property: 'value',
        stops: [
          [2, 5],
                        [1000, 10],
                        [8000, 20],
        ]
      }
    }

  });
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like AverageNitrate (I assume this was the property you were trying to plot) was a string. Converting to int did the trick.

Also I referenced it in the styling expression instead of the generic 'value'

```
data.features.forEach((datum)=>{
          datum.properties.AverageNitrate = parseInt(datum.properties.AverageNitrate)
      })
      
      //Add the the layer to the map
      map.addLayer({
        id: 'csvData',
        type: 'circle',
        source: {
         type: 'geojson',
         data: data
        },
        paint: {
          'circle-color': '#dd502c',
          'circle-stroke-width': 1,
          'circle-stroke-color': '#dd502c',
          'circle-opacity': 0.5,
          "circle-radius": {
            property: 'AverageNitrate',
            stops: [
              [2, 5],
                            [1000, 10],
                            [8000, 20],
            ]
          }
        }
      
      });
```

Here is a link to the edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mojsc6pn/35/